# Dropdown menu flickering over slider, only on Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I'm pretty new to all this, so apologies if this is a dumb question:

I've got a Magento site located here: http://www.thisisnotavegetable.com It uses responsive design, and when displayed on mobile-width browsers, the topmenu becomes a javascript-enabled dropdown.

This all works fine, except on the home page (where it is loading over a javascript-enabled slider), and only on Chrome for Android. On that browser, the dropdown flickers and link text won't display. I assume this is a jQuery issue, but I'm not advanced enough to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated!
Alex

Below is the jQuery for the dropdown (I think). The slider is ioSlider. I hope someone can help me without needing to see that jQuery, because it's unformatted and the license says I'm not supposed to post it.

```
if (jQuery('#categories-accordion').length){
    jQuery('#categories-accordion li.level-top.parent ul.level0').before('<div class="btn-cat"><div class="inner"></div></div>');
    if(mobileDevice == true){
        jQuery('#categories-accordion li.level-top.parent').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).on({
                click: function (){
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('touched')){
                        jQuery(this).addClass('touched closed').children('ul').slideToggle(200);
                        clearTouch(jQuery(this));
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }else{
        jQuery('#categories-accordion li.level-top.parent .btn-cat').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggle(function(){
                jQuery(this).addClass('closed').next().slideToggle(200);
            },function(){
                jQuery(this).removeClass('closed').next().slideToggle(200);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would be great, if you could post the jQuery Code :)

Flickering might be solved by using hardware acceleration. You can force the browser to use hardware acceleration by adding "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);" into the css class of the mobile menu.

```
      mobileMenu {
          ...
          -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          }
```

Comment: Thank you Phil - I tried this but it actually caused the flickering to occur on every other page, not just the home page (where it flickers only on top of the slider). Again, this is only on Chrome for Android. In every other browser it's just fine! I added the jQuery code for the dropdown. Is there anything else I can add to help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for the late answer. Don't know if you already fixed the problem. I think it would be nice, if you would use css transform for animating the dropdown. Better performance and I think it should fix the flickering issue.